# Simplest way to collect/view logs from an Azure Cloud Service Worker Role

Tags: azure, logging, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics, wadslogtable

I have an Azure Cloud Service Worker Role with Diagnostics enabled.
Nlog with a console writer is used to write app logs.

I know that those logs end up in WADLogsTable on my Storage account.
The question is what is the best way to view/analyze those log entries.
I found a tool named "Azure Diagnostics Viewer", but it's only able to view/analyze logs for the last day. Also, I'd like the tool to be able to extract "fields" from my log entries, e.g. TimeStamp, Log Level and so on.

Am I missing something that's on the surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-storage) highlights tools that can be used to view diagnostic data stored in WADlogsTable. Relevant excerpt below.

**Tools to view diagnostic data** Several tools are available to view the data after it is transferred to storage. For example: 
• Server Explorer in Visual Studio - If you have installed the Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio, you can use the Azure Storage node in Server Explorer to view read-only blob and table data from your Azure storage accounts. You can display data from your local storage emulator account and also from storage accounts you have created for Azure. For more information, see Browsing and Managing Storage Resources with Server Explorer. 
• Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer is a standalone app that enables you to easily work with Azure Storage data on Windows, OSX, and Linux. 
• Azure Management Studio includes Azure Diagnostics Manager which allows you to view, download and manage the diagnostics data collected by the applications running on Azure.

**To analyze the saved logs for insights** , I recommend using Azure Log analytics. Reference [this lin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-overview)k for usage details - overview snipped below;
Log Analytics plays a central role in Azure management by collecting telemetry and other data from a variety of sources and providing a query language and analytics engine that gives you insights into the operation of your applications and resources. You can either interact directly with Log Analytics data through log searches and views, or you may use analysis tools in other Azure services that store their data in Log Analytics such as Application Insights or Azure Security Center.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata (https://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-studio).

It has comprehensive functionality for viewing, filtering, searching etc. the WADLogsTable.

Hope this helps.